# disable scroll event listener for sometime

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I want to disable scroll event listener for sometime

I have implemented slider here

my code is here

```
$(window).bind('DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
            if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
                //scroll down
                if(swiperV.activeSlide<(total-1)){
                    console.log('down');
                    swiperV.swipeNext();
                    console.log('down-after');
                }
            } else {
                //scroll up
                if(swiperV.activeSlide>0){
                    console.log('up');
                    swiperV.swipePrev();
                    console.log('up-after');
                }
            }
            //prevent page fom scrolling
            return false;
        });
```

now i want to disable scroll until the slide change

when I will call swiperV.swipeNext(); it will change slide.

Comment: Are you actually trying to disable the `DOMMouseScroll` event, which is only implemented in Firefox, or are you trying to disable the standard `scroll` event, but just picked the wrong event name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finaly use

for firefox

```
$(window).bind('DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
     $(window).unbind('DOMMouseScroll');
            if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {                    
                if(swiperV.activeSlide<(total-1)){                    
                    swiperV.swipeNext();                                      
                    $(window).bind('DOMMouseScroll');
                }
            } 
            else {                    
                if(swiperV.activeSlide>0){                    
                    swiperV.swipePrev();                    
                    $(window).bind('DOMMouseScroll');
                }
            }                
            return false;
        });
```

For other

```
    $(window).bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
$(window).unbind('mousewheel');
                    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
                        //scroll down total
                        if(swiperV.activeSlide<(total-1)){                            
                            swiperV.swipeNext();  
                          $(window).bind('mousewheel');
                        }
                    } else {
                        //scroll up
                        if(swiperV.activeSlide>0){                            
                            swiperV.swipePrev();   
                          $(window).bind('mousewheel');
                        }
                    }
                    //prevent page fom scrolling
                    return false;
                });
```

Thanks to adeneo and Ishan Jain

Answer (score 0):

You can unbind the eventlistner by

```
$(window).unbind('DOMMouseScroll');
```

you can unregister any event handler by `$.unbind()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Name the event handler, then you can reference it within its body like so:

```
$(window).bind('DOMMouseScroll', function SomeName(e) {
    if (SomeReason) $(window).unbind('DOMMouseScroll', SomeName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `unbind` event-listner and after `swiperV.swipeNext();` again `bind` it : -

```
$(window).bind('DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
     $(window).unbind('DOMMouseScroll');
            if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {                    
                if(swiperV.activeSlide<(total-1)){
                    console.log('down');
                    swiperV.swipeNext();                  
                    console.log('down-after');
                    $(window).bind('DOMMouseScroll');
                }
            } 
            else {                    
                if(swiperV.activeSlide>0){
                    console.log('up');
                    swiperV.swipePrev();
                    console.log('up-after');
                    $(window).bind('DOMMouseScroll');
                }
            }                
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: hey thanks its working fine in Mozilla Firefox but how do same for chrome,safari,IE

Answer (score 0):

For IE, Opera, Safari you can use

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function (e) { //your code });
```